# Apps checking for app data in sd card instead of internal memory

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, app-data

I have an android phone with 13gb usable internal memory. I have many apps installed in it like fifa etc. I have been using the phone for quite some time without any sd card. Today I got an sd card and inserted it, and all of a sudden all installed apps are checking their app data in sd card instead of internal memory. Default write disk is internal memory and no apps have been transfered to sd card. I noticed this when I wanted to play fifa and it asked to download data first. How can I make my apps work without removing my new sd card?

Device 
OS : 4.4.2
Model : infinix x507
Kernel: 3.4.67

Comment: Is the device rooted? I can suggest something but requires root access and Xposed framework installed.

Comment: @Firelord yap, it's rooted